# NoSuchElementException while using toDF from Spark / Livy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reflection, hbase, livy

I am attempting to produce a Spark Dataframe from within Spark, which has been initialised using apache Livy.

I first noticed this issue on this more complicated hbase call:

```
 import spark.implicits._

 ... 

        spark.sparkContext
          .newAPIHadoopRDD(
            conf,
            classOf[TableInputFormat],
            classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
            classOf[Result]
          )
          .toDF()
```

But i found i could get the same thing to occur on a simple:

```
 import spark.implicits._

  ...

  val filtersDf = filters.toDF()
```

Where, `filtersDf` is just a sequence of case classes.

The common issue is the `*.toDF()`, however it also occurs with `*.toDS()`, which makes me think that the implicit resolution on `import spark.implicits._` is not working. The underlying objects to be converted to dataframes do have data.

The error stack looks like it relates to runtime implicit resolution using scala runtime reflection.

Note that i have checked and both spark and the compiled code both use the same version of Scala (2.11) .

The exception i get is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:420)
scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:417)
scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:277)
scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.parentSymbols(Symbols.scala:2117)
scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.openPackageModule(SymbolTable.scala:301)
scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.openPackageModule(SymbolTable.scala:341)
scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$LazyPackageType$$anonfun$complete$2.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:74)
scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$LazyPackageType$$anonfun$complete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:71)
scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$LazyPackageType$$anonfun$complete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:71)
scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.slowButSafeEnteringPhaseNotLaterThan(SymbolTable.scala:263)
scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$LazyPackageType.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:71)
scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$1.scala$reflect$runtime$SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$super$info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:174)
scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:123)
scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$1.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:174)
scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$1.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:174)
scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.thisInfo(Types.scala:2194)
scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseClasses(Types.scala:2199)
scala.reflect.internal.tpe.FindMembers$FindMemberBase.<init>(FindMembers.scala:17)
scala.reflect.internal.tpe.FindMembers$FindMember.<init>(FindMembers.scala:219)
scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.scala$reflect$internal$Types$Type$$findMemberInternal$1(Types.scala:1014)
scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.findMember(Types.scala:1016)
scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.memberBasedOnName(Types.scala:631)
scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.member(Types.scala:600)
scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48)
scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticPackage(Mirrors.scala:204)
scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.staticPackage(JavaMirrors.scala:82)
scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.init(Mirrors.scala:263)
scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$class.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$$createMirror(JavaMirrors.scala:32)
scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$$anonfun$runtimeMirror$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:49)
scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$$anonfun$runtimeMirror$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:47)
scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$class.runtimeMirror(JavaMirrors.scala:46)
scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
```

My working assumption is that I am missing a dependency or import and this is some kind of scala-ism.

I have yet to find any other references to this issue. Ultimately i think it is probably down to imports/dependencies but so far I can't quite see what it is. Any help greatly appreciated.  I'm keen to know ways to fix the issue or alternatively to create data frames via less magical approaches than `toDf()`.

Spark info:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.2.0-mapr-1901
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_191)
```

Comment: Can you check the count of the rdd before toDF() and check the results? Like, spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf,classOf[TableInputFormat],classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],classOf[Result]).count()

Comment: I have checked and the rdd has data.  But i don't think it is the RDD itself but more related to the `toDF` call which comes via an implicit.  If you look closely at the error it is a scala reflection error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error on the same version of spark, however, I was seeing the error appear while reading a csv from hdfs, this being an example of what I was doing:

```
val csv: DataFrame = ss
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .csv(filePath)
println(csv.count())
```

[This](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/ScalaReflection.scala#L45) is where I'm seeing the error originate from within spark.

I produced a small example of this failing and tried to isolate what was causing the issue. I was using the livy scala programmatic api to submit jobs to spark. I found that it was failing due to the types I passed as parameters to spark via livy, which makes sense as this is a scala reflection error.

For example this failed:

```
case class FailingJob(someSeq: Seq[String], filePath: String) {
...
def call(scalaJobContext: ScalaJobContext): Unit = {
    // It doesn't really matter what I do here.
// Main this is that the seq is used in some way.
val mappedSeq = someSeq.map(s => s.toUpperCase())

val ss: SparkSession = scalaJobContext.sparkSession

val csv: DataFrame = ss
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .csv(filePath)

println(csv.count())
...
 for {
     _ <- livyClient.submit(FailingJob(someSeq, path).call)
...
```

Whereas this was successful:

```
case class SuccessfulJob(someArray: Array[String], filePath: String) {
...
def call(scalaJobContext: ScalaJobContext): Unit = {
    // It doesn't really matter what I do here.
// Main this is that the seq is used in some way.
val mappedSeq = someArray.map(s => s.toUpperCase())

val ss: SparkSession = scalaJobContext.sparkSession

val csv: DataFrame = ss
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .csv(filePath)

println(csv.count())
...
 for {
     _ <- livyClient.submit(SuccessfulJob(someArray, path).call)
...
```

So if I pass in a param with the type `Seq` this fails, which makes me think that this is an issue with the serrialization/deserialization wihtin `kryo`. The other thing to note is that this error does *not* throw if I reference the value as a property on an object. I've tried upgrading to spark 2.4 with no luck. I'm using livy version `0.6.0-incubating`. My work around currently is to transform the objects to use `Array` types rather than `Seq`. I suspect other scala specific types will also fail, although I have not tried this yet.

[Here](https://github.com/steviej08/FailingLivySparkJob) is my reproduction of this issue which includes the work around. I appreciate this doesn't answer the question but hopefully it helps someone else struggling debugging the issue in other scenarios. I've also submitted an issue with [livy](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LIVY/issues/LIVY-720?filter=allopenissues) to see if they can give some more insight into what's going on.